# Using ASP MVC without Annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm just learning how to do ASP MVC. All of the tutorials I see use a combination of Html.LabelFor and the DisplayAttribute. Personally, I'm not a big fan of adding these kinds of annotations to my model objects and I'd like to know if there is an accepted alternative. I thought this might be a place for something like Knockout or Backbone, but I'm so new to this stuff that I'm having difficulty wrapping my brain around the different pieces.

I know this has probably already been asked and answered; I can't even figure out how to google it :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can skip Data Annotations

you can write

```
<label for='@(var1)'>@Name</label>
```

or

```
<label for='name1'>Text</label>
```

or

```
Html.Label("ControlName", "Name")
```

or

```
Html.LabelFor  with data anot.
```

any of this will be correct

also using helpers with lamda expressions (Html.LabelFor) is much slower than Html.Label or simple html code `<label for='@(var1)'>@Name</label>`

It is true for all asp.net mvc html helpers